# Windows 10 LTSC: Deleted guest wifi profile shows up again

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

we are running Windows 10 LTSC on our kiosk computers. At one location, they're connected to the internet via wifi. At that location they have a wifi set up for the kiosk (WPA2) and another open wifi for guests. The kiosk should always be connected to the WPA2 network but for some reason it also discovers the guest wifi, adds it as a known network, and connects to that instead.

So far we have tried the following solutions multiple times each:

- delete the guest wifi via the "Known Networks" GUI
- delete it via the command line: `netsh wlan delete profile "guests"`
- keep it in the list but disable the automatic connection
- disable Hotstop 2.0 via the GUI & via the registry
- disable wifi sensing via the registry

None of those approaches seems to work: the guest wifi will show up as a known network again after a short while and sometimes connect to it causing issues.

Is there any setting which we are missing? Is there a good way to find out why the guest wifi shows up again and connects?

Thank you for any ideas & solutions.

Comment: Can you provide a sanitized version of the name of the WiFi network.  I suspect this might be a case where the guest network is being discovered before the regular network due to the name.  However, even with a guest network, it shouldn’t be automatically connecting unless the checkbox is marked for that network

Comment: @John - The author is talking about the guest WiFi network ID not a guest account within Windows

Comment: You can stop the wireless profile from reappearing if you wish.   netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="WiFi Network Name" networktype=infrastructure

Comment: @Ramhound: thank you for your response. The wifi name is "CMP-Guests" with CMP being the 3-letter acronym of that location's company. Our own SSID is completely different but would come last in alphabetical order if that is what you mean? But why would Windows prefer an unknown network instead of the known, secure one?

Comment: @John: I'll apply the filter to the kiosk and will monitor if the guest wifi reappears or not. Thank you!

Comment: To give an update: the filter does prevent the kiosk to find & connect to the guest wifi. This is great, thank you @John! It feels like a workaround by hiding a problem not resolving its root, but it does solve the issue.

Comment: I will post an answer then, as using the filter does solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn’t provide any options in the Settings app or Control Panel, but you can easily block a WiFi network using the Command Prompt. To block a WiFi network, all you need is the network name or SSID. You can get a WiFi network name by looking at the network connections pop-up. (Click on the network icon in the taskbar.) When you block a WiFi network, it will no longer appear in the network connections pop-up, and you won’t be able to connect to it.

To start, search for “Command Prompt” in the Start menu, right-click on it and select the option “Run as Administrator.”

In the command prompt window, execute the below command to block the WiFi network. Replace “WiFi Network Name” with the actual SSID or network name.

netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="WiFi Network Name" networktype=infrastructure

As soon as you execute the command, said WiFi network will be added to the blacklist filter, and you will be no longer be able to see or connect to it.

In the future, if you want to allow the WiFi network, all you have to do is to delete the entry from the blacklist. To do that, execute the below command while replacing “WiFi Network Name” with the actual blocked network name.

netsh wlan delete filter permission=block ssid="WiFi Network Name" networktype=infrastructure

If you don’t remember the actual name, then use the below command. It will list the names of all the allowed and blocked WiFi networks.

netsh wlan show filters

**Follow up** addition by the author of the question:

To add to this, there is also a way to whitelist a single (or more) ssid and block all others:

"netsh wlan add filter permission=allow ssid="WIFI-Name" networktype=infrastructure" & "netsh wlan add filter permission=denyall networktype=infrastructure"

Comment: To add to this, there is also a way to whitelist a single (or more) ssid and block all others: 
"netsh wlan add filter permission=allow ssid="WIFI-Name" networktype=infrastructure" & 
"netsh wlan add filter permission=denyall networktype=infrastructure"

Comment: Thank you. I have added your addition to the answer and attributed it to you. This may be helpful for others.